# How to get the current URL into clipboard using Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimperator

**Why:**

I've just stumbled upon the [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org) Firefox plugin and have never felt this free from using a mouse to surf the web (without having to lose all the eye candy with Lynx ;)

Firefox can now be more easily used in fullscreen mode (<kbd>F11</kbd>). I keep the tabs showing for a visual aid and would like to also get rid of the address and search bars. However, I'm used to quickly grabbing the current URL to copy to clipboard (like switching tabs, grabbing URL of another tab, switching back and pasting as a link in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)).

When I hide the navigation bar in Firefox, the usual <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to highlight the current page/tab's URL no longer works.

**Question:**

How to get the current URL into clipboard using [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By yanking. `y` yanks current URL, `Y` gets highlighted text. You should see something like

> Copied text to clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/...